# how to install OS in pandrive and run on any pc or laptop?

Tags: boot, format, playonlinux

My laptop is currently not being formatted properly.

Every time I try to install any operating system it installs, but before I can move to drive, it crashed and gets back to boot screen, it doesn't even reaches the OS boot menu.

I was wondering If I could be helped to install an OS completely within a pen drive , then access my drives just by connecting my laptop to my pen drive.

Please guide me with this situation, I have some urgent data on one of my drive which I need to recover anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing Ubuntu to a Flash Drive via Startup Disk Creator**

Note: Back up ALL data from your Flash Drive before proceeding!

- Insert your Ubuntu CD and restart your computer, booting from the Live CD
- Insert a 1GB or larger USB flash drive
- Navigate to System > Administration > Startup Disk Creator

[image]

- Select your Flash Drive from Disk to use
- Choose to Erase Disk (Make sure you have backed up any important data first)

[image]

- Select the partition related to your Flash Drive
- For Persistence, select the option Stored in reserved extra space and adjust the slider to desired capacity
- Click the Make Startup Disk button

[image]

- A bar appears to indicate the progress of the install. Once the installation is complete, remove the CD, restart your computer and set your Boot Menu or System BIOS to boot from your USB device
- Done